# Subscription Payment options for Android App

Tags: android

I have a website that provides a service that customers pay a monthly subscription to via Paypal to use.

I would like to write an Android App that my customers could use to access the same service  but have the following questions:

1. If I release the App into the Market as free but customers need to register for a paid subscription on the website then this will be seen as a breach of the Market T&Cs and I will get booted - is that correct?
2. If I release the App into the market using a paid subscription model then I cannot incorporate Paypal subscription into the app as I am only allowed to use Google checkout - is that correct?
3. I cannot release the App into the market using a paid subscription model through Google Checkout because in-App payment does not support subscriptions - is that correct?

Thanks for any help and advice.

Comment: Please take a look at the discussion in a similar question http://stackoverflow.com/q/2787738/1321873

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to put the app on google play. You could create the app and distribute it yourself. After all its only supposed to be used by your customers.